# Database scheme for web log analytics

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema

I analyse web logs (nginx) and want store (organize) result in DB.
After analyse and aggregate my result looks like:

- Date and Time (Truncate it by hours)
- Country
- City
- URL (Page on the website)
- Referrer (source website)
- UTM_Medium
- UTM_Campaign
- c_sessions
- c_views
- avg_session_time
- c_js_event_1
- c_js_event_2
- c_js_event_3

And so on, about 30 columns.

For that data I prepare "big table"

```
CREATE TABLE public.cca_data_hours
(
  datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  id_geo_country integer NOT NULL,
  id_geo_city integer NOT NULL,
  id_web_page bigint NOT NULL,
  id_web_referrer bigint NOT NULL,
  id_utm_campaign bigint NOT NULL,
  id_utm_medium bigint NOT NULL,
  c_sessions integer,
  c_views integer,
  avg_sd integer,
  c_jse_1 integer,
  c_jse_2 integer,
  c_jse_3 integer,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT cca_data_hours_pri PRIMARY KEY (datetime, id_web_page, id_web_referrer, id_utm_campaign, id_utm_medium, id_geo_country, id_geo_city)
)
```

I expect 100 000 000 records.

**My selections**

- I want see all data by countries, cities
- I want see data per page
- I want see data per source (referrer)
- I want see data per page, source and utm campaign
- Some other combinations

**My questions**

- Is it normal use so many columns as primary key (index)? Primary key now contains 7 columns, it may up to 10-15 columns in the future.
- I think this is a simple solution how to organize this data in one  object-relational DB table. Do you know better solution, practice?

Comment: do you realize that a pkey(a,b,c) can only be used to seek b,c iff you also search on a.  shy of that it can be used only in an index scan. So adding a ton of columns to a primary key doesn't suffice the covering index problem you just slow down inserts unless your search uses all of those columns.

Comment: Adding to the practical remarks from Evan, I would question if it made sense to have a PK at all.  What would you use it for when storing/processing logs?

Comment: Nice question, really, do I need it at all!? May be better to add 1-2-3 indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many columns in a primary key sounds strange, at least.  That means to me that the data is not really adhering to a sensible uniqueness definition - this is more often than not like this in the case of logs.  For this reason, I wouldn't even try to find a PK here, just define indexes based on the queries used against the table.  One could call this opportunistic indexing ;)

Note that in general, in a relational models PKs are very important.  Here it is more the case the data is not really relational, only stored in a RDBMS.